# It's possible to get next.js request object globally?

Tags: next.js, fastify

I am using `fastify` with `next.js` and I need to include tracing (`requestId` is the problem so far). What I am doing right now is creating a `fastify` onRequest hook and generating a `requestId` value and setting it in request object (could be as a request header as well). What I want is to get access to this request object for two reasons:

1. In logger object (`pino` in this case, I want to include the `requestId` in all custom server-side logs).
2. In all request that needs to be made to other services need to include the `requestId` in headers.

Maybe I am missing something trivial and I'm not doing it the best way.

**HERE SOME SNIPPETS**

**This how I am generating the reqId**

```js
const fastify = fastifyFactory({
  logger, // logger configuration (Pino instance with custom configuration, see below)
  genReqId: () => {
    return Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .slice(-6);
  }
});
```

**pino instance**

```js
const pino = require('pino');
const logger = pino({
  messageKey: 'message',
  prettyPrint: true,
  changeLevelName: 'severity',
  useLevelLabels: true,
  base: {
    serviceContext: {
      service: 'web'
    }
  },
  level:'info'
});
module.exports = {
  logger
};
```

**This is a plugin to gets the reqId generated and setting it to a query property within request object**

```js
const tracing = function tracing(fastify, opt, next) {
  fastify.addHook('onRequest', (req, res, nextRequest) => {
    const { id } = req;
    const logger = fastify.log.child({ reqId: id });
    req.query.reqId = id;
    fastify.log = logger; //overrides the current fastify logger to include the reqId in all custom logs
    nextRequest();
  });
  next();
};
tracing[Symbol.for('skip-override')] = true;
module.exports = tracing;
```

I have no problem when using `fastify.log.info(...)` because how logger is overrided in each request, it will include the `reqId` as a child log. The problem is that I want to create a generic logger to use at any part and fastify logger is not available in React components (for example to write logs at `getInitialProps`). Another important think is tha I need to include this `reqId` in all request I send to other services (ex: when fetching data), this is why I tried to store this value in request object but need to get it.

Comment: I think this feature is already supported via [genreqid](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Server.md#genreqid), do you tried it?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes but this feature what allows is to set a custom function to generate the reqId. I am using currently but the problem is that out of the scope of fastify logger I have no access to this property (reqId). I tried using cls-hooked to store the generated reqId but I couldn't use it from any React component (maybe did something wrong)

Comment: do you have some snippet to let me understand better the context?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I already added snippets in the question

Comment: I have a working snippet, just the last thing: could you add your pino config?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, already added pino config

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a project build with:

```
npx create-next-app --example custom-server-fastify custom-server-fastify-app
```

And changing the `server.js` with:

```
const Next = require('next')
const Fastify = require('fastify')

// your pino config
const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: {
    level: 'info',
    prettyPrint: true,
    changeLevelName: 'severity',
    useLevelLabels: true,
    base: {
      serviceContext: {
        service: 'web'
      }
    }
  },
  genReqId: () => { return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6) }
})

// your plugin
const aPlugin = function yourPlugin (fastify, opts, next) {
  fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, reply, next) => {
    request.log.info('hello')
    const { id } = request
    request.query.reqId = id
    next()
  })
  next()
}
aPlugin[Symbol.for('skip-override')] = true
fastify.register(aPlugin)

[.... other generated code]
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000

[.... other generated code]
      fastify.get('/*', (req, reply) => {
        console.log('-------->', req.id, req.query.reqId) // both your id is ok
        return app.handleRequest(req.req, reply.res).then(() => {
          reply.sent = true
        })
[.... other generated code]
      })
```

Then:

```
npm run dev
# another console
curl http://localhost:3000/
```

It will print out:

```
[1558441374784] INFO : Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000
    serviceContext: {
      "service": "web"
    }
> Ready on http://localhost:3000
[1558441405416] INFO : incoming request
    serviceContext: {
      "service": "web"
    }
    reqId: "2i810l"
    req: {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/",
      "hostname": "localhost:3000",
      "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
      "remotePort": 57863
    }
req id ----> 2i810l
--------> 2i810l 2i810l
[ event ] build page: /
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[1558441406171] INFO : request completed
    serviceContext: {
      "service": "web"
    }
    reqId: "2i810l"
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
    responseTime: 753.012099981308
```

So I think the misunderstanding is in the request object that is the Fastify request and not the Node.js "low level" request object, that could be accessed with `request.req`.

Moreover, running `fastify.log = logger;` is dangerous because it means that each request override and create a new logger and change the logger for the fastify instance, this is not safe, and as shown it is not necessary.

If you want more child logger (per route prefix per example) I suggest exploring/using the [`onRegister` hook](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Hooks.md#application-hooks).

---

EDIT:

Now the custom hook print:

```
[1558443540483] INFO : hello
    serviceContext: {
      "service": "web"
    }
    reqId: "zjuhw2"
```

Comment: the problem is not solved with this.  The purpose of `fastify.log = logger;` is because if you try to write a custom log you will see that reqId is not included (not the default logs that fastify writes, like incoming request and request completed, those as you showed works well with reqId included) and I need it. This is my main question (maybe not very clear, sorry for my English), how to get this reqId even in React components

Comment: Ok, I will checkit out 

Comment: `I have update the response to print the reqId when you log something`
edit the answer to fix this

still checking for the id in React component

Comment: The problem with genReqId: () => { return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6) } in pino is that will generate a new reqId. If you run all you will se that reqId of custom log is diferent of reqId of fastify logs and needs to be the same because are in the same request